# How to display in the text the closest spreaded fire object from a List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class SpreadedFireDistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public GameObject player;

    private List<GameObject> spreadedFires = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spreadedFires = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spreaded Fire").ToList();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spreadedFires.Count; i++)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, spreadedFires[i].transform.position);
            text.text = "Player distance from the fire: " + distance.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

in the text.text I want to display each time the closest spreadedFires[i] object.
so when I move the player the text.text will change and show each time the closest spreadedFires[i] object.

something like: "Player distance from the spreadedFire 1 is: " + the distance from spreadedFire 1

and if the player is now closer to spreadedFire 2 then the text will change to:

"Player distance from the spreadedFire 2 is: " + the distance from spreadedFire 2

I tried this but it's not working.  sometimes it's changing the fire name when I move the player close to another fire but sometimes it's not , most of the time it's not changing the fire name.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class SpreadedFireDistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public GameObject player;

    private List<GameObject> spreadedFires = new List<GameObject>();
    private float oldDistance = 9999;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spreadedFires = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spreaded Fire").ToList();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spreadedFires.Count; i++)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, spreadedFires[i].transform.position);
            if (distance < oldDistance)
            {
                text.text = "Player distance from the fire" + i.ToString() + ": " + distance.ToString();
                oldDistance = distance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

screenshot of the spreaded fires and the objects in the hierarchy:

[image: spreaded fires]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not really checking what fire is the nearest fire. Your `oldDistance` eventually gets too small.
You are comparing `oldDistance` with the new `distance` here: `if (distance < oldDistance)`.

Example: The player gets near Fire1 and stops at a distance of 0.2. `oldDistance` is now set to 0.2. Now the player leaves Fire1 and goes to Fire2 but only to a distance of 0.3. `oldDistance` is still set to 0.2 so the condition will never return `true` thus resulting in the text not changing.

I propose to change the code so you get a array / list of all the fire distances and just get the first element after sorting it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpreadedFireDistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public GameObject player;

    private List<GameObject> spreadedFires = new List<GameObject>();
    private (GameObject, float)[] spreadedFiresDistanceSorted;
    private GameObject curNearestFire;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spreadedFires = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spreaded Fire").ToList();
        spreadedFiresDistanceSorted = new (GameObject, float)[spreadedFires.Count];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Don't run if there isn't any fire
        if (spreadedFires.Count <= 0)
            return;

        // Get all the distances from player position to each fire and put GameObject and distance in tuple
        for (int i = 0; i < spreadedFires.Count; i++)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, spreadedFires[i].transform.position);
            spreadedFiresDistanceSorted[i].Item1 = spreadedFires[i];
            spreadedFiresDistanceSorted[i].Item2 = distance;
        }

        // Order array with distances
        spreadedFiresDistanceSorted = spreadedFiresDistanceSorted.OrderBy(x => x.Item2).ToArray();
        curNearestFire = spreadedFiresDistanceSorted[0].Item1;

        text.text = "Player distance from the fire" + curNearestFire.name.ToString() + ": " + spreadedFiresDistanceSorted[0].Item2;
    }
}
```